# How come I can't spread props with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So this works with no typescript errors:

```
<Box hAlign={"RIGHT"} vAlign={"CENTER"} />;
```

But this gives me an error:

```
const commonBoxProps = {
  hAlign: "RIGHT",
  vAlign: "CENTER",
};
```

...

```
<Box {...commonBoxProps} />;
```

Error:

```
Type '{ hAlign: string; vAlign: string; margin: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLD...
```

Comment: Please include the definition of your `Box` component.

Comment: include whole error

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with styled components:

```
const ColumnBox = styled(Box).attrs({
  hAlign: "RIGHT",
  vAlign: "CENTER",
})``;
```